# How to scrape image in ion-img if the src is php script which is generating captcha code

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic4

I'm **scraping** website for the college project which will be used to display the result.

The problem is the results are protected by a captcha code.

I tried scraping using the node HTML parser but when I extract `src` attribute it says `captcha.php`.

Inspect element of that captcha code image is below

```
<img src="captcha.php" class="control-label ">


const img = <HTMLElement[]><any>root.querySelectorAll('img') ;
       console.log(img[1]);
       let imgt1 =<HTMLImageElement> img[1];
       let tmp3 =JSON.stringify(imgt1.attributes);
       et con1 = JSON.parse(tmp3)
       console.log(con1)
       this.image= con1;
       console.log(this.image.src)//output captcha.php
```

at the front end

```
   <ion-img [src]="image.src"></ion-img>
```

and the front end image is not displaying and it showing broken image

what should I do?

edit:
website also uses cookies also 'PHPSESSID'

Answer (score 0):

Just because the url of the element is pointing at a php file doesn't mean it's returning a php web page.

You can write php to return any type of data you want. In this case its returning an image.

You can try downloading the captcha.php file. In theory it should have an image contents inside of it but probably it will detect that the script is not being called from the right location and show some kind of error image.

The point of a captcha is to specifically stop this kind of thing. You are a robot trying to access the system. If it was a simple case of pulling the image out via a script then it would make the captcha system pretty pointless.

When you say this is for a college project, what do you mean? Is the project to try to break a captcha system? Or are you just trying to cheat somehow?